# jQuery datepicker keeps reopening in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, datepicker

jQuery's datepicker keeps reopening after clicking on a date in IE 8, even on their demo page:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Does anyone know how to fix this? I don't know about the demo page, but I am having the exact same problem with jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.15.

Also, setting the minDate and maxDate options does not seem to have any effect in IE 8.
The above seems to also be true with IE 7.

Comment: I just ran across this same issue.  It does appear to be new behavior introduced in 1.8.15.  I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: Downgrading to jQuery UI 1.8.14 did the job for me.

Comment: There is a "stable" version of 1.8.16 that has this issue fixed as well.

Comment: Thnaks! I guess 1.8.16 just came out from the oven. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.8.14 [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/VZts7/) in IE8.

The re-opening seems to be a bug in 1.8.15, see [broken demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VZts7/1/).

Comment: Thanks! I downgraded to 1.8.14, and it fixed the calendar reopening issue. Hope someone has a solution for the minDate and maxDate issues.

Comment: Ok, the minDate and maxDate was my error. I was passing the date in the wrong format. I was passing new Date('2011-08-16') instead of Date('08-18-2011') as minDate option.

Comment: Glad you got the other part solved. I searched the jQuery UI bug list but nothing that matches what you found. I will raise it myself tomorrow if I can't find an existing bug.

Answer (score 8):

The following resolved this issue for me (using jQuery 1.7.2 / jQueryUI 1.8.20)

```
var $input = $('#date');

$input.datepicker({
  /* 
   * your other settings here 
   */
  onSelect : function() { $input.blur(); },
  onClose  : function() { $input.change(); }
});

$input.on('change paste', function(evt) {
  // process new date input here
});
```

Comment: You could also use `$(this)` within the `onSelect`'s & `onClose`'s callback functions.

Comment: @koiyu, you can but then you are calling the jQuery constructor again to create a new instance for the input element. More efficient to use a cached instance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with IE8 and the customized min version of Jquery UI 1.8.16 (all options selected)  When I used the full released version of 1.8.16 the problem went away.

Comment: Thanks for that imput! I'll make sure I am using the full version.

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same problem for jquery ui 1.11.2. The following snippet solved the problem in our case:

```js
var input = $('<input>');

input.datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    this.lastShown = new Date().getTime();
  },
  beforeShow: function() {
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    return this.lastShown === undefined || time - this.lastShown > 500;
  }
});
```